# Quickly filter a perl hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash, filter

I have a perl hash of hashes like the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ID_1' => {
                           'FILE_B' => '/path/to/file/file1',
                           'FILE_C' => '/path/to/file/file2',
                           'FILE_A' => '/path/to/file/file3'
                         },
          'ID_2' => {
                           'FILE_B' => '/path/to/file/file4',
                           'FILE_A' => '/path/to/file/file5'
                         },
          'ID_3' => {
                           'FILE_B' => '/path/to/file/file6',
                           'FILE_A' => '/path/to/file/file7'
                         }
          ...                       
}
```

I would like to  get a list of all keys of members in the main hash that have `FILE_C` defined. In the example, this will return only `ID_1`.

I know how to do this in a cumbersome loop (iterating all keys, checking if `FILE_C` is defined, if so — pushing the key to an array, finally returning this array), but I have a feeling there's a single-liner or even a function for this …

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, perl has the [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) function:

`my @keys = grep { defined $hash{$_}{FILE_C} } keys %hash;`